# Asp.NET MVC static content caching doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I want to cache static content of my asp.net mvc 3 app. I added this tag in web.config to cache for 10 days:

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"  cacheControlMaxAge="10:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

but it seens doesn't work (checked using YSlow and Fiddler). Any ideas why?

Comment: I tried on DevServer, IIS Express and IIS 7.5

Comment: Does the server send the Cache-Control header at all ?

Comment: Yes. Cache-Control:max-age=36000

Comment: Well, then it works. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments we've exchanged above, I'd say that the client side caching works.

Your server sends:

```
 Cache-Control:max-age=36000
```

Which means, that the client should cache it for 10 hours (60 * 60 * 10 == 36000).
If you actually want 10 days, the configuration is:

```
cacheControlMaxAge="10.00:00:00"
```

Remember that the client might decide to retrieve the resource again regardless of your cache headers, for any number of reasons (such as the client side cache has been purged, the user requested a full refresh, the client doesn't implement client side caching properly, etc. etc.)

How did you arrive at the conclusion that it doesn't work ?

Comment: I checked it using YSlow Fiddler and Chrome dev tool. Every time I refresh page it always makes request to static content  (http status 200).

Comment: The server tells the client the right thing, but refreshing in this case also means to refresh the cached resources. If you just nnavigate to the page, the browser should use the cached version